# Move a std::future to another std::future

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference, future, stdmove

I'm trying to move a std::future member of class to another member of same class.

I need to do that because if I want to call std::vector.push_back(MyClass),  I need to delete the copy constructor with a simple reference and create another one with double ref because my class contain a std::future member.
When i move the std::future, G++ says :

```
call to deleted constructor of 'std::future<int>'
_future(std::move(p_myclass._future));
note: 'future' has been explicitly marked deleted here
future(const future&) = delete
```

But for me, std::move returns a double ref and not a single. So I don't really know where this error comes from.

I tried the assignement operator = with double ref but doesnt work either.

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::future<int> _future;
public:
    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass(const MyClass&&);
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass &) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass &&);
};
```

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &&p_myclass) : _future(std::move(p_myclass._future)) {};

MyClass& MyClass::operator=(MyClass &&p_myclass)
{
    this->_future = std::move(p_myclass._future);
    return (*this);
};
```

Of course my std::future is initialised on main constructor, but there is no need to paste it here.
Both doesn't work.
Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p_myclass` is `const`, and then so is `p_myclass._future`. That's why it can't be moved from; moving from an object requires modifying it. `_future(std::move(p_myclass._future))` attempts to copy it instead, but of course `std::future` is not copyable.